# SQL get max values under certain conditions when using two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

*I'm currently having the following two tables in my **Oracle** database.*

```
Table Continent with fields:
| CONTINENT | CONTINENTNAME |

Table Land with fields:
| LANDCODE | LANDNAME | CONTINENT | NUMBEROFLANGUAGES |
```

I want to display the continentname, the landname and the number of languages as the result. Under the following condition: **display from each continent the landname with the highest number of languages**.

**Current result** 
*i got this query which will show the country with the most languages in the world like so:*

```
CONTINENTNAME | LANDNAME | NUMBEROFLANGUAGES
--------------------------------------------
Asia          | India    | 26
```

Only i end up here with only one continent instead of all continents in the world. Am i using the wrong approach here or am i close in solving this query? I would love to know how to solve this SQL puzzle.

**Used Query**

```
SELECT c.CONTINENTNAME, l.LANDNAME, l.NUMBEROFLANGUAGES
FROM land l
INNER JOIN continent c 
ON c.CONTINENT = l.CONTINENT
   WHERE l.NUMBEROFLANGUAGES =
   (  SELECT MAX(l.NUMBEROFLANGUAGES)
      FROM land l
   );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close in concept.  I just moved your SELECT MAX() query in as a join and joined on based on that to the original land table.

```
SELECT 
      c.CONTINENTNAME, 
      l.LANDNAME, 
      l.NUMBEROFLANGUAGES
   FROM 
      land l
         INNER JOIN continent c 
            ON l.CONTINENT = c.CONTINENT
         INNER JOIN ( SELECT l2.CONTINENT,
                             MAX(l2.NUMBEROFLANGUAGES) maxLang
                         FROM 
                            land l2 
                         group by
                            l2.CONTINENT) preQuery
            ON l.CONTINENT = preQuery.CONTINENT
            AND l.NUMBEROFLANGUAGES = preQuery.maxLang
```

Comment: This query still gives me the same result. Only one record with Asia and not per continent the land with the highest number of languages.

Comment: @LarsMertens, updated to include inner query group by specific continent

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I had to correct

```
with max_language as (
    SELECT l.CONTINENT, max(l.NUMBEROFLANGUAGES) language_count
    FROM land l
    group by l.CONTINENT
)
select *
  from land l1,
       continent c,
       max_language ml
 where c.CONTINENT = l1.CONTINENT
   and l1.continent = ml.continent
   and l1.NUMBEROFLANGUAGES = ml.language_count;
```

Comment: This query currently gives duplicate continents. What i need is per continent the land with the highest number of languages.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method for doing this in Oracle uses aggregation and `keep`:

```
SELECT c.CONTINENTNAME,
       MAX(l.LANDNAME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY l.NUMBEROFLANGUAGES DESC) as LANDNAME,
       MAX(l.NUMBEROFLANGUAGES) as NUMBEROFLANGUAGES
FROM land l INNER JOIN
     continent c 
     ON c.CONTINENT = l.CONTINENT
GROUP BY c.CONTINENTNAME;
```

A more typical method uses analytic functions:

```
SELECT c.CONTINENTNAME, l.LANDNAME, l.NUMBEROFLANGUAGES)
FROM (SELECT l.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONTINENT ORDER BY NUMBEROFLANGUAGES DESC) as seqnum
      FROM land l
     ) l INNER JOIN
     continent c 
     ON c.CONTINENT = l.CONTINENT
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```